# How to sum numbers from a specific column?

Tags: python, file, numbers, sum, multiple-columns

I'm trying to make a program that can sum all numbers in a column from a text file.

Here is a link that shows the first 5 lines form the text file.

[image: img]

How would i sum all the numbers from for example the column FXM?

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: That's not a text file...

Comment: @odin fossil is this a text file? with the table setup like this in the file? or is it a different type of file?

Comment: I know it's not a text file. It's just the screenshot of the first lines, to give an example of what it looks like.

Comment: @odinfossli: would it be possible to paste a small sample text file (first three lines for instance). Right know parsing might fail on your side due to small differences in the format.

Comment: What format is your text file? If it's CSV you can look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to see how to read the file. Then read the correct column for each row of the file and sum up the values.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have a tab delimited text file there. This is a simple solution function with an example of usage.

```
import csv
def colsum(filename, delimiter, colname):
    reader   = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter='\t')
    headers  = next(reader)
    entries  = [ x for x in reader ]
    index    = headers.index(colname)
    result   = sum( [ float(entry[index]) for entry in entries ] )
    return(result)

def main():
    print(colsum('test_data.txt', '\t', 'DD06'))

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your best bet would be to use a CSV excel file to store this kind of data. You would then need to open the file and read the file like this...

```
import csv 
file = open(path, newline='')
read = csv.reader(file)

header = next(reader)

data = []
for row in reader: #This includes all your rows
    #Here you specify the data types of all of your rows
```

You will need to make some adjustments to make this work for columns.

Then, depending on the index of the column you want, you can just write a loop to iterate through all of the elements of the list.

```
ex.
sum=0
for element in column[6]:
     sum+=element #Assuming that you already specified in the previous loop 
                  #that these elements were floats
```